# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer to compensate for mobile covers

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer. However, when there is a mobile cover, which covers the edge, some of the gestures are not recognised. How do I compensate for it? The current code is:

```
   let edgePan = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(screenEdgeSwiped))
        edgePan.edges = .left
```

Should I change the .edges property?

Comment: What's "mobile cover"?

Comment: sorry. I meant.. bumper cases

Comment: like this one: https://www.igeeksblog.com/best-iphone-6-bumper-cases/ . I have seen a situation where they had a thicker one, that rises a few centimeters above the screen and left edge swipes were not being registered.